# How to click on a button with force using java selenium web driver

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

I am using selenium web driver with java.

And developing automation for my app in facebook, so whenever I add my app for first time in facebook, it is asking for permissions with okay button

I am trying to click on okay button with my code but that is not working.

Is there a better way to click on okay button using selenium web driver with java?

What I tried is:

```
1)driver.findElemenr(element).click();

2)Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.click(element)   

3)Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(element).click()

4)Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.KeyDown(element, Keys.ENTER);
```

Please let me know the reason before if you want to downvote my question

Comment: `Click a button with force` what does this mean? And what does `not working` mean?

Comment: Click a button with force in the sense, if the button is not clicked for the first time, is  there a code to click it again until it disappears (means with loops or anything)...not working means even if I click the button with above mentioned four ways, the button is not getting clicked sometimes but sometimes working

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [isEnabled()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) method in Selenium. What you can do is, after you click the button using webdriver you can check the status of the button and repeat the click process if the button is still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You just try with logic something like below.

```
int i=0;
while(isElementPresent(button) && i<10)
{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(button).click();
                i++;
}
```

The above code will try to click on button until it present or ***i*** (int i)reached 10. (loop breaking point)

You can find isElementPresent method implementation [here](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/07/iselementpresent.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
 WebDriverWait button = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);      
 button.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
 button.click();
```

This will wait 60 secs for the button to be clickable,if condition (element is clickable) is met before 60 secs, well and good, button will be clicked, else an exception will be thrown...

[*ExpectedConditions* class provides many useful methods](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).